# Effectively unit test an AngularJS directive which is manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a simple directive with AngularJS to add a smooth scrolling effect to any link.

I have published my work here: https://github.com/arnaudbreton/angular-smoothscroll
Everything works in a real context but I can't figure out how-to properly unit test it.
I [wrote a test](https://github.com/arnaudbreton/angular-smoothscroll/blob/master/test/spec/directives/smoothscroll-test.coffee) that can't pass because `$window.pageYOffset` is not incremented as expected.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can mock your $window object and update the pageYOffset in your test

Comment: Yes, that could make the test pass but I would prefer a test as close as possible from the real context. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a pull request that makes your tests run. https://github.com/bennyjo/angular-smoothscroll/commit/e660a8e1a4497907a9c74d9e359f2bbfa0b8326c

Basically the problem was that there was no space that the window could be scrolled into. Hence, no scrolling was possible and the tests failed correctly. I added some height on the body element to make the window scrollable.

```
$('body').height(window.innerHeight*2).append @target
```

I also did reset the scroll position before each test. If we don't do this the second test will fail.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: Great! Just saw and accept your pull request, thanks for your contribution. I've just updated the repo with an other pull-request.